# SQL Query to get the latest product for multiple product migration entries

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

Below table stores the product migration data. For example PROD1 got migrated to PROD2. I need help in building an optimal sql query which returns me the latest version of the product. For example - if input is PROD1, I get PROD5 as output. Similarly, if input is PROD3, I get PROD5 as output.

| Product From | Product To |
| --- | --- |
| PROD1 | PROD2 |
| PROD2 | PROD3 |
| PROD3 | PROD4 |
| PROD4 | PROD5 |

Comment: What have you tried? Have a look at [Hierarchical Data Traversal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-hierarchy-traversal)

Answer (score 0):

Using `WITH RECURSIVE` Can solve your problem as follows :

Just put the product you want to check the first select `WHERE Product_from = 'PROD1'`

```
WITH RECURSIVE products_paths (n, Product_from, Product_to, path) AS
(
  SELECT 1, Product_from, Product_to, CAST(CONCAT(Product_from, ',', Product_to) AS CHAR(400))
    FROM products
    WHERE Product_from = 'PROD1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n+1, p.Product_from, p.Product_to, CONCAT(pp.path, ',', p.Product_to)
    FROM products_paths AS pp 
    JOIN products AS p ON pp.Product_to = p.Product_from
)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(path,',',1) as input, SUBSTRING_INDEX(path,',',-1) as Output
FROM products_paths 
ORDER BY n desc
limit 1;
```

[Documentations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-hierarchy-traversal)

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/K2yFswmJ)